# Is the restriction of an injective sheaf on a closed subscheme still injective?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, adjoint-functors, pullback

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme, and let $i:Z\to X$ be the inclusion of a closed subscheme $Z$. Let $\mathcal{I}$ be an injective sheaf of modules on $X$.

> **Question.** Is $i^*\mathcal{I}$ still an injective sheaf on $Z$?

The difficulty seems to lie in the fact that $Z$ is closed: I do not know whether $i^*$ has a left-adjoint (and if yes, whether it is an extension by zero).

Comment: This is not true. Take $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A) $, with $A$ a Gorenstein ring of Krull dimension $0$; then $\mathscr{O}_X$ is injective. Now take $Z= \operatorname{Spec}(B) $, where $B$ is a quotient of $A$ which is *not* Gorenstein; then $\mathscr{O}_Z=i^*\mathscr{O}_X$ is not injective.

Comment: And you do know that there is no left adjoint already in the affine case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3055802/left-adjoint-to-the-tensor-functor

Comment: Outch! Thank you two very much, for both comments.